# Load an assembly (dll) from a network drive in C#

Tags: c#, dll

I am trying to load an dll from network folder in my C# exe.

System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(xPath + "\" + t[0] + ".dll");

I am getting the following error -

```
  RefusedSet=""
       Url=file://<network drive>/folder/raterType.dll
       StackTrace:
            at raterType.raterType.raterTypeCode(String a)
       InnerException:
```

What Assembly settings do I have to do, to give full trust to the dll from my exe, so it loads it without any restrictions?

Comment: Where is the rest of your error?

Comment: the line ended up at InnerException when I copy it to the clipboard. I would try to get the remaining part, however, it is basically security permission restrictions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to CAS [policy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2009/06/08/more-implicit-uses-of-cas-policy-loadfromremotesources.aspx). You need to give full trust permission.

If it does not work even after that, try to first load the file into memory (byte Array, using System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes()), and then load the assembly from in memory file data using the [Assembly.Load()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h538bck7.aspx) overload.

Comment: In my environment, loading the assembly from a byte array was the only solution I was able to get working.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You need to give "full trust" to the assembly you're trying to load from a network location. Here is a [step-by-step guide](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832742).

Comment: definitely a vote up, but a question - If I grant the assembly (dll) full trust, would it be loaded by any exe from any shared drive in the future? Can I grant assembly full trust while loading from the exe itself?

Comment: @amit_pandey there are different ways to configure trust, but basically you're saying any EXE can access that assembly from its current location. If you change the share, you have to change the trust settings. You'll have to read up on trust settings to make sure you configure this correctly for your needs.